# Why does the event 'transitionend' fires twice?

Tags: javascript, html

I am practicing my javascript doing the 30days of javascript challenge.

I cannot quite understand why the following code makes the 'transitioned' event fire twice.
I only have one property called transform in my css and I am checking it with the `e.propertyName` conditional inside the function removeTransition.

This line is what it seems to fire **twice**:

```
key.addEventListener("transitionend", removeTransition);
```

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="keys">
          <div data-key="65" class="key">
            <kbd>A</kbd>
            <span class="sound">clap</span>
          </div>
          <div data-key="83" class="key">
            <kbd>S</kbd>
            <span class="sound">hihat</span>
          </div>
          <div data-key="68" class="key">
            <kbd>D</kbd>
            <span class="sound">kick</span>
          </div>
          <div data-key="70" class="key">
            <kbd>F</kbd>
            <span class="sound">openhat</span>
          </div>
          <div data-key="71" class="key">
            <kbd>G</kbd>
            <span class="sound">boom</span>
          </div>
          <div data-key="72" class="key">
            <kbd>H</kbd>
            <span class="sound">ride</span>
          </div>
          <div data-key="74" class="key">
            <kbd>J</kbd>
            <span class="sound">snare</span>
          </div>
          <div data-key="75" class="key">
            <kbd>K</kbd>
            <span class="sound">tom</span>
          </div>
          <div data-key="76" class="key">
            <kbd>L</kbd>
            <span class="sound">tink</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>

        <script>
          window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
            const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);

            if (!audio || !key) {
              console.log("no key");
              return;
            }

            audio.currentTime = 0;
            audio.play();
            key.classList.add("playing");
            key.addEventListener("transitionend", removeTransition);
          });

          function removeTransition(e) {
            console.log(this);
            if (e.propertyName !== "transform") {
              return;
            }
            e.target.classList.remove("playing");
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>

This is the css file:
```

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/b9r5sEL.jpg) bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: 0.4rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  transition: all 0.07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  color: #ffc600;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S. I have solved the issue by moving the transitionend event outside the keypressed event but I would like to understand why it is not working this way.

Andrea

Comment: Your code adds a new (duplicate) handler for `transitionend` **every** time the `keydown` handler fires. You should move the `addEventListener('transitionend', ...` call to somewhere where it will only be called once (because you aren't calling `removeEventListener`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It should still fire once when I press one of the keys for the first time though, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transactionend event has associated with transition style of "key" class.
Which reacts by adding one more class "playing". 
It fired when you add playing class and again when you remove it.
Also you use "All" in your transition style which call this event multiple of style attribute change.

**Solution :** I think it is not feasible with transactionend event. Because it fires ones when it done transition and once more when back to original. Try some different logic or clarify.

**Hint :** It is better to use "setTimeout" function to remove "playing" class after transition time elapse.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Yes it does indeed fire once at the end of the transition and once more when it reverts back the transition. Will probably use 'setTimeout' even if it might not be precise due to the event loop timing. Also if someone changes the css transition time they also need to change the setTimeout time.